# Numerical integration with fixed abscissas

Tags: numerical-methods, integration

Can I do an integral, possibly using Gaussian quadrature, when the abscissas are fixed (for reasons that I don't want to get into right now); i.e., is it possible to calculate the weights for fixed abscissas that I don't get to choose?

Comment: Question has also been posted to MathOverflow, so I vote to close it here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In fact, if the abscissas $x_i$ of a weighted interpolatory quadrature rule

$$\int_a^b w(x) f(x)\;\mathrm dx\approx\sum_i w_if(x_i)$$

are given, and you need to generate the corresponding weights $w_i$, there are [algorithms](http://dx.doi.org/10.1007/BF01396453) by Sylvan Elhay and Jaroslav Kautsky (based on [earlier work](http://dx.doi.org/10.1007/BF01390210) by Kautsky and Gene Golub for the case of quadratures with both fixed and free knots) that are based on symmetric eigenvalue methods *a la* Golub-Welsch, and are slightly more stable than the usual approach of solving the Vandermonde system generated by the moments $\int_a^b w(x) x^k\mathrm dx$. They have [published](http://dx.doi.org/10.1145/35078.214351) a [FORTRAN implementation of their methods](http://www.netlib.org/toms/655) in the ACM Collected Algorithms; translating that into your favorite computing language (if you're not using FORTRAN, that is) is entirely up to you.

---

On the other hand, if you do have exact values for the $x_i$ and the moments $m_i=\int_a^b w(x) x^k\mathrm dx$ available, and you can do exact arithmetic, solving the Vandermonde system is feasible.

In particular, remember that for a weighted $n$-point quadrature rule with $n$ preset abscissas, it is customary to demand that the quadrature rule be able to exactly integrate functions of the form $w(x)p(x)$, where $p(x)$ is a polynomial with an degree from $0$ to $n-1$. ($n-1$ points uniquely determine a corresponding $n$-th degree polynomial passing through those points). However, it may well be that due to the special configuration/distribution of the points, the quadrature rule could do much better than expected. (Two examples come to mind: Simpson's rule is meant to be exact for quadratics, but is able to integrate cubics exactly, and the $n$-point Clenshaw-Curtis rule, whose $x_i$ are the extrema of Chebyshev polynomials, [behaving favorably with regards to accuracy](http://www.cse.illinois.edu/courses/cs591mh/trefethen/Clenshaw-Curtis.pdf).) Newton-Cotes is but a special case of this, where the $x_i$ are equispaced over the integration interval.

Thus, to obtain the weights $w_i$ from the $x_i$ and the $m_i$, one needs to solve the primal Vandermonde system

$$\begin{pmatrix}1&1&1&\cdots&1\\x_1&x_2&x_3&\cdots&x_n\\x_1^2&x_2^2&x_3^2&\cdots&x_n^2\\\vdots&\vdots&\vdots&\ddots&\vdots\\x_1^{n-1}&x_2^{n-1}&x_3^{n-1}&\cdots&x_n^{n-1}\end{pmatrix}\cdot\begin{pmatrix}w_1\\w_2\\w_3\\\vdots\\w_n\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}m_1\\m_2\\m_3\\\vdots\\m_n\end{pmatrix}$$

Gaussian elimination will work here, but it is more economical to use the [Björck-Pereyra algorithm](http://dx.doi.org/10.1090/S0025-5718-1970-0290541-1), which is based on Newton interpolation. This takes $O(n^2)$ effort as opposed to the $O(n^3)$ effort needed by Gaussian elimination.

But, again, for inexact arithmetic, the methods by Elhay and Kautsky will (generally) give more accurate values for the weights.

---

As a last warning, you will want to check the signs of the weights, whether you compute them through the Vandermonde route or the Elhay-Kautsky route. Beware if the weights are not of the same sign; it usually means that the underlying interpolating polynomial is quite oscillatory, and there might be cancellation of significant digits when the quadrature formula is used.

Answer (score 1):

Absolutely.  Section 4.5 of [Numerical Recipes](http://nr.com/) describes how, as will many numerical analysis books.  Obsolete versions are free.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. If I'm understanding you correctly you're referring to the section titled "Orthogonal Polynomials with Nonclassical Weights". Is this correct? I'm not 100% sure I understand, though. What I am constrained to use is the roots of the polynomials in Eq. (4.5.6). The section above is for when we know the modified moments of Eq. (4.5.30). I don't really see how to get from one to the other.